# Can I collaborate my own kernel module and eBPF program?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, ebpf

I am trying to write a project in which I need to write a customized kernel module and some eBPF programs. In this project, I use eBPF programs to collect some data and store these data in the eBPF map, and these data are needed in my kernel module.

What I want is that in my kernel module, I can call some functions like `ebpf_get_data(struct data_tag key)` to get the data from eBPF maps, and such `ebpf_get_data()` function is exposed to my kernel module by the eBPF program. How can I achieve this goal?

I searched the internet for solutions but couldn't find any. I sincerely appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Why the mix of both? Couldn't you use a kernel module for everything if you're loading one anyway?

Comment: Have you figured out how to access eBPF maps from a kernel module?